# Extracting Date value from DateTime field using sosl query

Tags: apex

Is it possible to extract date part from a datetime field through SOSL query..?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. I would suggest you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to accomplish. Generally you could use Date.valueOf() to get a date object from DateTime field .

Comment: SOSL, SOQL or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Maybe..

If you're attempting to use the extracted date part to filter the query somehow, then no, it's not possible to modify a DateTime field within a SOQL query. The recommended solution for this is to create a new [formula field](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_formulas.htm) that contains the date part you would like to use in a query then use that field instead of the DateTime field in the query.

However, if you would like to extract the date part for use in Apex code, you can do that simply by using the [DateTime Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm). Check the documentation for the `DateTime`.

```
Account a = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate From Account Limit 1];
Date AccountCreatedDate = a.CreatedDate.date();
system.debug(AccountCreatedDate.format());
```

This also works:

```
Account a = [Select Id, Name, CreatedDate From Account Limit 1];
Integer month = a.CreatedDate.month();
Integer day = a.CreatedDate.day();
Integer year = a.CreatedDate.year();
system.debug(month+'/'+day+'/'+year);
```

Output (same for both):

```
USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|7/11/2013
```

Comment: You can also use DateTime.date():  Date d = a.CreatedDate.date(); String formattedDate = d.format();

Comment: Good point; that works better actually! I updated my answer.